# Azure Active Directory B2C - Display and collect user input with data from Restful service

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In my organization, User Sign In flow is following:

- Sign in with email and password
- Select organization to sign in (one user belongs to multiple organizations)

  - only one organization can be selected during Sign In process
- Output Access token should contain custom claim with organization
  UUID

With Azure AD B2C via custom policy is possible to query external API and get list of organizations which belongs to the user, but it seems, there is no easy way how to let user select one of organizations and then add selected organization UUID to the output claim.

The most suitable way is to use [DropdownSingleSelect](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/azure//active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#dropdownsingleselect) DisplayClaim, but it cannot be populated with dynamic data from external API -> list of organizations

In AAD B2C we can use Javascript during User flow/Custom policy's Self  asserted technical profile to call external API, render UI controls and collect user input, but it cannot access output claim and insert data to it -> insert info about selected organization.

Do you know how to get data from external Restful API and let user to choose his preferred organization during Sign In flow and add this information to Access token? Thanks

Comment: Using the Multi-tenant application, configuring the endpoint as 'common' will be simplest solution. why this doesn't solve your scenario?

Comment: Don't know how Multi-tenant application can be useful in this scenario. Can you explain how exactly it could help, please?

Comment: If you set the Authorization endpoint to `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` and based on the user specific organizations email it will be redirected to particular org login screen once user gets authenticated you can receive the access token based on the organization.
which avoid the first login and api call for fetching organization information, binding to drop down and all. Reference [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant-custom?tabs=applications)

Comment: In this scenario you expect that user has unique email for every organization. In my scenario user has one personal email, which he uses to Log In. This user (with one personal email) has access to multiple organizations and during Sign In workflow he should select one of organizations. Selected organization UUID (or another identification) should be included in Access token.

Comment: Hi @Bluf Thanks for you wait, right now there is no right example/GitHub sample to provide you. Theorically you should be able to fill the output claim using JS/jQuery